# Geofinder not working after upgrade

Tags: geofinder

I just upgraded from ee 1.6.7 to ee 2.5.5.  The original site used geofinder and so I installed the latest version of geofinder and the relevant page does not load.  It could be unrelated, but is there any change in the syntax  I should know about?  This is an except from the template:

```
{exp:geofinder:location_results channel="results_groups" status="open" limit="10" geoquery="{segment_6}" radius="100"  latitude="{latitude}" longitude="{longitude}" google_maps_api_key="" distance_mode="miles" disable="member_data|category_fields|trackbacks"  orderby="state|title" sort="asc|asc"}
```

Comment: "Does not load" meaning an absolute blank page or just no data from this tag?

Comment: Loads only the menu from the bottom of the page:  Home  |   About RESULTS  |   Calendar  |   On Campus  |  

Jobs and Internships  |   Contact Us

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there might be a PHP error occurring.

First, turn on debugging in the CP by enabling **[Display Output Profiler](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html#display-output-profiler)** and **[Display Template Debugging](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html#display-template-debugging)**. When you reload the page, you will see debugging info at the bottom.

Then check the following:

1. Make sure you are logged in as a Super Admin user
2. Make sure [**Debug Preference**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/output_and_debugging_preferences.html#debug-preference) is set to "PHP/SQL error messages shown only to Super Admins"
3. In your config.php change $config['log_threshold'] = 0; to $config['log_threshold'] = 4;
4. In you config.php make sure $debug = 1; is set
5. Check your php error logs

---

This article is also a good read for tracking down issues in EE:
[**Troubleshooting ExpressionEngine**](http://focuslabllc.com/blog/troubleshooting-expressionengine)

Comment: Thanks for your help Anna.  Turns out the problem was unrelated to geofinder.  Has to do with the defunct navigation addon (cpNavBreadcrunbs) which caused some of the path information to change.

Comment: Great. Please make sure to most your remedy as an answer to your question...